# Why would iron found in a nanoparticle not technically be a mineral?

Tags: minerals

An quote from an article at https://newatlas.com/science/antarctica-blood-falls-iron-red-water/ states, "Now a new study has examined samples of the water and found that the iron appears in an unexpected form. It’s not technically a mineral – instead it takes the form of nanospheres, 100 times smaller than human red blood cells."

Why does being in nanoparticle form cause iron to not technically be a mineral?  If not a mineral then what would the iron be classified as?

Comment: From the article you linked: “In order to be a mineral, atoms must be arranged in a very specific, crystalline, structure. These nanospheres aren't crystalline, so the methods previously used to examine the solids did not detect them.”

Comment: The article is not forthcoming with information.  It seems iron salts are involved and an ion analysis of the colorless water would be interesting. What anions are present?

Comment: Where can non-crystalline iron be found?  How is it produced?  I am suspecting some biological process?  Is the iron in hemoglobin crystalline?